# Mongodump from secure Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, ssl

In order for me to connect to this [secure] Mongo instance I have to run the following command:

`mongo --ssl --host sampleHostname --sslPEMKeyFile /path/to/user.pem --sslCAFile /path/to/mongoca.cer --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism=MONGODB-X509`

I am trying to do a `mongodump` command to get the data but I keep running into the following errors:

**Attempt 1**

`mongodump -d mydb`

`Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`

**Attempt 2**
[Can't create backup mongodump with --db. Authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993168/cant-create-backup-mongodump-with-db-authentication-failed)

`mongodump -d mydb --authenticationDatabse '$external'`

`Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`

**Attempt 3** Using the same command as how I connect.

`mongodump -d mydb --ssl --host sampleHostname --sslPEMKeyFile /path/to/user.pem --sslCAFile /path/to/mongoca.cer --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism=MONGODB-X509`

`Failed: error getting collections for database 'mydb': error running 'listCollections'. Database: 'mydb' Err: not authorized on 'mydb' to execute command {listCollections: 1, cursor: {} }`

I have tried the same command with sudo but it still returns the same error.

**Attempt 4** [Minimum permission for using mongodump (to dump a specific db)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490291/minimum-permission-for-using-mongodump-to-dump-a-specific-db)

`mongodump -d mydb --ssl --host sampleHostname --sslPEMKeyFile /path/to/user.pem --sslCAFile /path/to/mongoca.cer --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism=MONGODB-X509 --excludeCollection=system.indexes`

`Failed: error getting collections for database 'mydb': error running 'listCollections'. Database: 'mydb' Err: not authorized on 'mydb' to execute command {listCollections: 1, cursor: {} }`

I am stuck and I am eventually going to run `mongorestore` but I do not want to run this without making sure I am able to backup first. I imagine the solution for `mongodump` will resolve any possible issues I may have with `mongorestore` (if any).

Comment: Shot in the dark, here, but have you tried `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` or `--sslAllowInvalidHostnames`?

Comment: @Adam I just tried adding both headers (and each separately) but it still returns the same error: `Failed: error getting collections ... etc.`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Two more suggestions for debugging: 1) could you try to dump a specific collection within your db? Use the `--collection` flag. 2) I'm not very experienced with `--authenticationDatabase` so this may be a moot point, but could you make sure that the user has admin privileges?

Comment: The first point it gives back: `Failed: error counting mydb.fruits: not authorized on mydb to execute command { count: "fruits", query: { } }`. However, according to the admin db table `system.users` I have the `dbOwner` role.

Comment: very weird. When you login using `mongo --ssl --host sampleHostname --sslPEMKeyFile /path/to/user.pem --sslCAFile /path/to/mongoca.cer --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism=MONGODB-X509` can you execute `mydb.fruits.find(yourQuery).count()`?

Comment: @Joey I suspect there is something wrong with your user's permissions; does it _definitely_ have the role _dbOwner_ for the _mydb_ database? Remember everything is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Adam yeah that returns 25.

Comment: @VinceBowdren there are only 2 users in the system.users. An admin user with one role of `"userAdminAnyDatabase"` for the `admin` db and another user (me) who has 2 roles. A role of `"dbOwner"` for the `mydb` db and a `"readWrite"` for the `mydb` db.

Comment: @Joey I have the exact same problem, found no solution so far, any progress on your side ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to this [blog post](https://habrahabr.ru/post/308740/) , looks you have to set the -u value with the CN when using 509 and $external.

```
mongodump --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile user.pem --sslCAFile cap.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --authenticationMechanism=MONGODB-X509 --authenticationDatabase '$external'  --host "rsTmpCloudManager/10.100.15.118:27017,10.100.16.237:27017,10.100.17.107:27017" -d testJoce -u "CN=???,OU=???,O=???,L=???,ST=???,C=??"
```